# Error in active reactive context - How to fix?

Tags: r, shiny

Hey I am trying to build a shiny app for the purpose of calculating per cent chance of defaulting and I thought I fixed all my issues until I hit

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

but whenever I try to build something reactive I get

```
Error in RET@get_where(newdata = newdata, mincriterion = mincriterion) : 
  object 'loanfilev3' not found
```

I've looked over stackoverflow and tutorials and none seem to really help

Here is my UI and Server code for the first error, if someone could please highlight my issue that would be greatly appreciated.

UI:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select the random distribution type ----
      numericInput("loan_amnt",
                   "Loan Amount:",
                   value = 5000,
                   min = 0,
                   max = NA),

      numericInput("int_rate",
                   "Interest Rate:",
                   value = 10.5,
                   min = 0,
                   max = NA),

      selectInput("term",
                  "Loan Term:",
                  c("36 months" = " 36 months", 
                    "60 months" = " 60 months")),

      numericInput("installment",
                   "Installment:",
                   value = 100,
                   min = 0,
                   max = NA),
      textInput("grade", "Grade:", "B"),

      textInput("emp_length", "Employment Length:", "5 years"),

      numericInput("annual_inc",
                   "Annual Income:",
                   value = 40000,
                   min = 0,
                   max = NA),

      numericInput("dti",
                   "Debt to Income Ratio:",
                   value = 5.4,
                   min = NA,
                   max = NA),

      textInput("sub_grade", "SubGrade:", "B2"),

      textInput("verification_status", "Verification Status:", "Verified"),

      textInput("home_ownership", "Home Ownership:", "RENT"),

      radioButtons("pymnt_plan", "Payment Plan:",
                   c("Yes" = "y",
                     "No" = "n"))
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Decision Tree", verbatimTextOutput("ct")),
                  tabPanel("Generlized Linear Model", verbatimTextOutput("dl")),
                  tabPanel("K-Nearest Neighbour", verbatimTextOutput("kn"))
      )
    )
  )
)
)
```

Server:

```
library(shiny)
library(pscl)
library(ROCR)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(pROC)
library(caret)
library(e1071)
library(RMySQL)
library(reshape2)

USER <- 'inft216'
PASSWORD <- 'rosemary'
HOST <- 'bruce3.dc.bond.edu.au'
DBNAME <- 'inft216'

db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = USER, password = PASSWORD, host = HOST, dbname = DBNAME)
loanfile <- dbGetQuery(db, statement = "select * from lendingClub;")
dbDisconnect(db)

library(party)

colnames(loanfile) = tolower(colnames(loanfile))

bad_indicators = c("Charged Off",
                   "Default",
                   "Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Charged Off",
                   "Default Receiver", 
                   "Late (16-30 days)",
                   "Late (31-120 days)")

loanfile$default = ifelse(loanfile$loan_status %in% bad_indicators, 1,
                          ifelse(loanfile$loan_status=="", NA, 0))
loanfile$loan_status = as.factor(loanfile$default)
loanfilev2 = dplyr::select(.data = loanfile,loan_status,loan_amnt,int_rate,term,installment,grade,emp_length,annual_inc,dti,sub_grade,verification_status,home_ownership,pymnt_plan) 
loanfilev2$grade = as.factor(loanfilev2$grade)
loanfilev2$sub_grade <- as.factor(loanfilev2$sub_grade)
loanfilev2$term <- as.factor(loanfilev2$term)
loanfilev2$emp_length <- as.factor(loanfilev2$emp_length)
loanfilev2$verification_status <- as.factor(loanfilev2$verification_status)
loanfilev2$home_ownership <- as.factor(loanfilev2$home_ownership)
loanfilev2$pymnt_plan <- as.factor(loanfilev2$pymnt_plan)
loanfilev2$loan_status <- as.factor(loanfilev2$loan_status)
loanfilev2$grade <- as.numeric(loanfilev2$grade)
loanfilev2$sub_grade <- as.numeric(loanfilev2$sub_grade)
loanfilev2$term <- as.numeric(loanfilev2$term)
loanfilev2$emp_length <- as.numeric(loanfilev2$emp_length)
loanfilev2$verification_status <- as.numeric(loanfilev2$verification_status)
loanfilev2 <- loanfilev2[complete.cases(loanfilev2),]
set.seed(69)
train_index <- sample(seq_len(nrow(loanfilev2)), size = 5000)
TrainData<- loanfilev2[train_index, ]

ct = ctree(loan_status ~ ., data = TrainData)
dl <- glm(formula = loan_status ~ .,data = loanfilev2, family = binomial)
kn <- train(form = loan_status ~.,data = TrainData, method = 'knn')

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  loan_status <- c(0)
  loan_amnt <- input$loan_amnt
  int_rate <- input$int_rate
  term <- input$term
  installment <- input$installment
  grade <- input$grade
  emp_length <- input$emp_length
  annual_inc <- input$annual_inc
  dti <- input$dti
  sub_grade <- input$sub_grade
  verification_status <- input$verification_status
  home_ownership <- input$home_ownership
  pymnt_plan <- input$pymnt_plan
  temp2 <- cbind(loan_status, loan_amnt, int_rate, term, installment, grade, emp_length, annual_inc, dti, sub_grade, verification_status, home_ownership, pymnt_plan)
  loanfilev3 = dplyr::select(.data = loanfile,loan_status,loan_amnt,int_rate,term,installment,grade,emp_length,annual_inc,dti,sub_grade,verification_status,home_ownership,pymnt_plan) 
  loanfilev3 = rbind(loanfilev3, temp2, deparse.level = 0)
  loanfilev3$grade = as.factor(loanfilev3$grade)
  loanfilev3$sub_grade <- as.factor(loanfilev3$sub_grade)
  loanfilev3$term <- as.factor(loanfilev3$term)
  loanfilev3$emp_length <- as.factor(loanfilev3$emp_length)
  loanfilev3$verification_status <- as.factor(loanfilev3$verification_status)
  loanfilev3$home_ownership <- as.factor(loanfilev3$home_ownership)
  loanfilev3$pymnt_plan <- as.factor(loanfilev3$pymnt_plan)
  loanfilev3$loan_status <- as.factor(loanfilev3$loan_status)
  loanfilev3$grade <- as.numeric(loanfilev3$grade)
  loanfilev3$sub_grade <- as.numeric(loanfilev3$sub_grade)
  loanfilev3$term <- as.numeric(loanfilev2$term)
  loanfilev3$emp_length <- as.numeric(loanfilev3$emp_length)
  loanfilev3$verification_status <- as.numeric(loanfilev3$verification_status)
  loanfilev3 <- loanfilev3[complete.cases(loanfilev3),]
    prediction1 = c(predict(object = ct, newdata = loanfilev3[886508], type = "prob"))
    output$ct <- renderPrint({
    as.data.frame(prediction1)[2,]*100

  })

})
```

Comment: Your code is too much to go through. Reduce it to bare minimum that captures your idea and problem.

Comment: Sorry about that I cut down the multiple predictors, this should be the bare minimum now - sorry again

Comment: That was just feedback. No need to apologize. Anyways, your question is about shiny reactivity so just focus your code on that. Understanding what drives what is the key here not the prediction problem itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All input bindings `(input$whatever)` need to be used in reactive context for example: inside `reactive()` or `observe` or `renderXXX` etc. In your case you are doing stuff like `loan_amnt <- input$loan_amnt` outside of reactive context and that's what the error is about. See my update below. I have added your prediction model to an `eventReactive` that is triggered by some action button `input$predict`.

```
# add this button somewhere in your ui.R -
actionButton("predict", "Predict!")
```

update to server.R -

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  prediction <- eventReactive(input$predict, {
    loan_status <- c(0)
    loan_amnt <- input$loan_amnt
    int_rate <- input$int_rate
    term <- input$term
    installment <- input$installment
    grade <- input$grade
    emp_length <- input$emp_length
    annual_inc <- input$annual_inc
    dti <- input$dti
    sub_grade <- input$sub_grade
    verification_status <- input$verification_status
    home_ownership <- input$home_ownership
    pymnt_plan <- input$pymnt_plan
    temp2 <- cbind(loan_status, loan_amnt, int_rate, term, installment, grade, emp_length, annual_inc, dti, sub_grade, verification_status, home_ownership, pymnt_plan)
    loanfilev3 = dplyr::select(.data = loanfile,loan_status,loan_amnt,int_rate,term,installment,grade,emp_length,annual_inc,dti,sub_grade,verification_status,home_ownership,pymnt_plan) 
    loanfilev3 = rbind(loanfilev3, temp2, deparse.level = 0)
    loanfilev3$grade = as.factor(loanfilev3$grade)
    loanfilev3$sub_grade <- as.factor(loanfilev3$sub_grade)
    loanfilev3$term <- as.factor(loanfilev3$term)
    loanfilev3$emp_length <- as.factor(loanfilev3$emp_length)
    loanfilev3$verification_status <- as.factor(loanfilev3$verification_status)
    loanfilev3$home_ownership <- as.factor(loanfilev3$home_ownership)
    loanfilev3$pymnt_plan <- as.factor(loanfilev3$pymnt_plan)
    loanfilev3$loan_status <- as.factor(loanfilev3$loan_status)
    loanfilev3$grade <- as.numeric(loanfilev3$grade)
    loanfilev3$sub_grade <- as.numeric(loanfilev3$sub_grade)
    loanfilev3$term <- as.numeric(loanfilev2$term)
    loanfilev3$emp_length <- as.numeric(loanfilev3$emp_length)
    loanfilev3$verification_status <- as.numeric(loanfilev3$verification_status)
    loanfilev3 <- loanfilev3[complete.cases(loanfilev3),]
    predict(object = ct, newdata = loanfilev3[886508], type = "prob"))
  })

  output$ct <- renderPrint({
    as.data.frame(prediction())[2,]*100
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much honestly, where specifically should I add the action button?

Comment: Just add it at some appropriate place wherever you want. It only makes sure that the prediction model will run only when you press it. Without it the model will run for every change in input and your app will be slow. You can add it at the end in the sidebarPanel.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but any clue as to why I'd be getting the error 
Error in $<-.data.frame: replacement has 886507 rows, data has 886508 
when I have complete cases to cut out all the NAs